# Core Data: sort using a PartialKeyPath instead of a KeyPath

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, sirishortcuts

## TL;DR

How to create an `NSSortDescriptor` using a `PartialKeyPath` instead of a `KeyPath`?

Or

How to convert a `PartialKeyPath` to a `KeyPath`?

When we declare `SortingOptions` in an `EntityPropertyQuery` implementation, we pass a `KeyPath` to the `EntityQuerySortableByProperty` initializer. But we do not get the same `KeyPath` in the `entities(matching:)` function's `sortedBy` parameter. Instead, it gives us a `PartialKeyPath`, and there is no way (afaik) to use this `PartialKeyPath` to sort in Core Data since `NSSortDescriptor` expects either a `KeyPath` or a `String`, not a `PartialKeyPath`.

## Details

I'm using the new query properties from AppIntents to filter my app's data in Shortcuts, but I'm unable to map the sorting attribute it gives me to the sorting attribute Core Data expects in the predicate.

Here's my `EntityPropertyQuery` implementation:

```
extension ArtistQuery: EntityPropertyQuery {

    static var sortingOptions = SortingOptions {
        SortableBy(\ArtistEntity.$name)
    }

    static var properties = QueryProperties {
        Property(\ArtistEntity.$name) {
            EqualToComparator { NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", $0) }
            ContainsComparator { NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS %@", $0) }
        }
    }

    func entities(matching comparators: [NSPredicate],
                  mode: ComparatorMode,
                  sortedBy: [Sort<ArtistEntity>],
                  limit: Int?) async throws -> [ArtistEntity] {
        Database.shared.findArtists(matching: comparators,
                                    matchAll: mode == .and,
                                    sorts: sortedBy.map { NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: $0.by, ascending: $0.order == .ascending) })
    }

}
```

And my `findArtists` method is implemented as follows:

```
static func findArtists(matching comparators: [NSPredicate],
                        matchAll: Bool,
                        sorts: [NSSortDescriptor]) -> [EArtist] {
    ...
}
```

As we can see in the `entities(matching:)` function, I'm using the `by` attribute from the `sortedBy` parameter to create the `NSSortDescriptor`, but it doesn't work because the `NSSortDescriptor` init expects a `KeyPath`, not a `PartialKeyPath`:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'PartialKeyPath<ArtistEntity>' to expected argument type 'KeyPath<Root, Value>'
```

So, can I create an `NSSortDescriptor` using a `PartialKeyPath` instead of a `KeyPath`? Or maybe converting a `PartialKeyPath` to a `KeyPath`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution thanks to this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/mralexhay/3c85fd0ae7f67806a91f2a7c080bac1b). There's no way to directly convert from an EntityQuerySort to an NSSortDescriptor. Instead, we have to convert it manually:

```
private func toSortDescriptor(_ sortedBy: [Sort<ArtistEntity>]) -> [NSSortDescriptor] {
    var sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor]()
    if let sort = sortedBy.first {
        switch sort.by {
        case \.$name:
            sortDescriptors.append(NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \EArtist.name, ascending: sort.order == .ascending))
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    return sortDescriptors
}
```